# Connection Pooling in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am unable to understand the use of `pool-db` and `connection` function
in this [connection pooling guide](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/reusing_connections.html).

```clj
(defn- get-pool
    "Creates Database connection pool to be used in queries"
    [{:keys [host-port db-name username password]}]
    (let [pool (doto (ComboPooledDataSource.)
                   (.setDriverClass "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                   (.setJdbcUrl (str "jdbc:mysql://"
                                     host-port
                                     "/" db-name))
                   (.setUser username)
                   (.setPassword password)
                   ;; expire excess connections after 30 minutes of inactivity:
                   (.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections (* 30 60))
                   ;; expire connections after 3 hours of inactivity:
                   (.setMaxIdleTime (* 3 60 60)))]
        {:datasource pool}))


(def pool-db (delay (get-pool db-spec)))


(defn connection [] @pool-db)

; usage in code
(jdbc/query (connection) ["Select SUM(1, 2, 3)"])
```

**Why can't we simply do?**

```clj
(def connection (get-pool db-spec))

; usage in code
(jdbc/query connection ["SELECT SUM(1, 2, 3)"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay ensures that you create the connection pool the first time you try to use it, rather than when the namespace is loaded.

This is a good idea because your connection pool may fail to be created for any one of a number of reasons, and if it fails during namespace load you will get some odd behaviour - any defs after your failing connection pool creation will not be evaluated, for example.

In general, top level var definitions should be constructed so they cannot fail at runtime.

Bear in mind they may also be evaluated during the AOT compile process, as amalloy notes below.

Comment: ITYM, cannot fail at compile time?

Comment: I would say further that the most important reason this is a bad idea is that your compile time environment may be totally different from your runtime environment, e.g. if you are building an uberjar to deploy. If you attempt to connect to the production database from your build server / development machine, that will fail, and you won't be able to build the jar.

Comment: I normally work in the REPL tbh but yes - totally - you are right on the AOT compilation issues.

Answer (score 1):

In your application, you want to create the pool just one time and reuse it. For this reason, [delay](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay) is used to wrap the (get-pool db-spec) method so that this method will be invoked only the first time it is forced with deref/@ and will cache the pool return it in subsequent forcecalls

Comment: Won't it still be creating the pool just one time if we use `(def connection (get-pool db-spec))`. I think it will still create the pool one time and store it in variable connection. Wont it return the stored value in subsequent calls in this case too?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the delay version a pool will be created only if it is called (which might not be the case if everything was cached), but the non-delay version will instantiate a pool no matter what, i.e. always, even if a database connection is not used.

`delay` runs only if `deref` is called and does nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an existing library to handle connection pooling, something like [hikari-cp](https://github.com/tomekw/hikari-cp), which is highly configurable and works across many implements of SQL.